# How do I call Google's API twice? I would like to geocode AND show a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-maps

script 1)

```
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=THISISMYAPIKEYBLABLABLA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

I then can make a script that makes a new map, which is awesome. It works fine.

script 2)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"> </script>
```

and then I just do some magic with a function and a textbox, and when a user types in the textbox, it automatically does a quick search, and gives me back the lat/lon values!

AND THEN I have this .js script that runs:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
      initilize();

});
function initilize() {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initilize);
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtautocomplete'));

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var location = "<b>Location:</b>" + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
        location += "<b>latitude:</b>" + place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
        location += "<b>longitude:</b>" + place.geometry.location.lng() + "<br/>";
        document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = location;
    });
};
```

When I test these scripts on their own, they work perfectly, but when I try to combine them I get error codes so:

QUESTIONS:

1) How do I run both? If I have both of the above scripts in the body, I get an error and it doesn't work. This is the main question and issue. I assume I have to do both of these in one script src= html tag.

2)(OPTIONAL) With twitter I had to run an express node server, and do OAUTH, what exactly is even going on with the above two scripts. One has an API key, the other doesn't, and I tried reading the documentation but it's a little confusing. So I guess what is the "best" way to get both to work and to access their API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put all the options in a single load of the API:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&key=THISISMYAPIKEYBLABLABLA&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured the rest out, much appreciated :)